# Cabling for ABS sensor and beeper on 2014 Kia Rio

Tags: part-identification, kia, electronics, abs

During the blizzard last weekend, I installed my tire chains. I must not have done so correctly, as the driver's side chain came loose. I was on a narrow section of interstate with no shoulder at night in near white-out conditions, so it didn't seem like a good place to stop. The wheel well has been broken for a while, so there was very little to stop it. By the time I did find a place to stop, the loose chains had ripped out the cabling for my ABS sensor and the speaker in the front fender (not sure if it has a different name, the thing that beeps when you lock or unlock, which is different from the horn).

[image]

I've gotten a new ABS sensor, but the chain also ripped out the cabling that the sensor attaches into. I am looking for replacement parts, and I can find replacements for the sensor easily enough, but for the cabling I am not sure what to look for. How do I replace this?